# Filter model in model records using Entity Framework using C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have following classes

```
class Patient
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public IList<Letter> letter { get; set; }
}

class Letter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public LetterStatus letterstatus { get; set; }
}

public enum LetterStatus
{
    sent= 0,
    draft = 1,
    notsent = 2
}
```

I want to fetch all the patient with a specific letter status. How can I fetch it?

I tried to use the following but it is not working:

```
var data = _context.Set<Patient>()
                   .IncludeAll(_context)
                   .AsQueryable();
data.Where(x => x.Letters.Find(y => y.LetterStatus == _letterStatus));
```

Comment: What does _it is not working_ mean?  Is there a compilation error?

Comment: There's no `IncludeAll` in EF Core. `Find` returns an object by its PK values, it can't be used in `Where`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modified LINQ to get the desired results -

```
var data = _context.Set<Patient>()
                   .Include(x => x.letter)
                   .Where(p => p.letter.Any(l => l.letterstatus == _letterStatus))
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created GetAllPatients function and give it a call. Then add where clause with .Any() to it. It worked for me. Thanks

```
var queryable = GetAllPatients(context);

queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Letter.Any(y => y.LetterStatus == (LetterStatus)_letterStatus));


private IQueryable<Domain.Patient> GetAllPatients(IDbConnectionQuery _context)
{
    return _context.Set<Domain.Patient>().IncludeAll(_context).AsQueryable();
}
```